# Specifying password field to SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership, custom-membershipprovider

I'm implementing SimpleMembershipProvider in a small MVC4 project, and I can already initialize the database connection using a customer-provided DB with the user and role tables already specified (those are called sp_person and sp_role).

The problem is, when I try to log in, the MVC app rejects my password with the typical "incorrect password" error message though I already know that it's the correct password. I suspect the problem is that SimpleMembershipProvider does not know where do I store the password (it's in the sp_person table, in the "ecampus_password" field) and that's why authentication fails.

How can I tell SimpleMembershipProvider where to look for the stored password?

Thanks in advance,

Léster

Comment: SimpleMembership comes with a default set of tables, did you changed them?

Comment: I haven't changed anything else, am I supposed to? Google gives me nothing.

Comment: As far as I know SimpleMembership works with a few tables, but the main ones are UserProfile (you can edit this one, by default it has UserId and userName) and _Membership (it has the UserId and all the login related info about the user). Maybe what is happening is that your logon feature is going against _Membership, rather the one you think is supposed to go. I suggest to use this _Membership table to store the passwords and login related info. Let me know

Comment: Actually, one of the requirements is that I can not alter the database structure in any way. I can't add new tables or change the way it stores data. I'm forced to use those two tables for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found that SimpleMembershipProvider is not the solution. In this case, I'm supposed to implement a custom provider.

Steps as follows:

- Add an Entity Data Model to the project that consumes only the tables related to the auth scheme (in my case, importing only `sp_person` and `sp_role`).
- Add `System.Web.ApplicationServices` as a reference to the project.
- Add a new class to the project, point to `System.Web.Security` in a `using` statement and make the class inherit from `MembershipProvider`. `MembershipProvider` is an abstract class, so implement it when asked.
- Add an object to the class of the type Entity Framework created for you when you added the data model (it's usually called `<CONNECTION_NAME>Entities`, you can change that when creating the model). Something like this:

  ```
  public class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
  {
      private MYCONNECTIONEntities db = new MYCONNECTIONEntities ();
  }
  ```
- Strictly, you might have to implement every property and method in the class, but for auth, you must implement `ValidateUser()`. Simply using a LINQ query to retrieve the user from your data model will do. Here's mine:

  ```
  var list = from u in db.st_person
             where u.ecampus_login == username
             && u.person_password == password
             select u;
  return list.Count() > 0;
  ```
- In `web.config`, under the `<authentication>` element, add the new provider like this:

  ```
  <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="PROJECT_NAME.MyMembershipProvider"/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
  ```
- Compile and test.